# Search Integer Array for duplicates

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm currently creating a very basic game in C# and I have an inventory system created which using a very simple command (Items.Add(id, amount)) you can add items to said inventory. What I want to be able to do, which my current system does not do is be able to effectively "search" my inventory array which is a 2D array holding the item id and item amount. My current system is like this:

```
public static void add(int id, int amount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Ship_Builder.Player.invCount; i++)
    {
        if (Ship_Builder.Player.inv[i, 0] == 0)
        {
            Ship_Builder.Player.inv[i, 0] = id; 
            Ship_Builder.Player.inv[i, 1] = amount;
        }
    }

    Ship_Builder.Player.invCount++;
}
```

and I want it to (in an else if) be able to search the array. I did have this:

```
else if (Ship_Builder.Player.inv[i, 0] == Ship_Builder.Player.inv[i + 1, 0])
{
    //Do
}
```

Before, but it didn't work how I wanted it to.
Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks,
Laurence.

Comment: Why use an array, why not a Dictionary?

Comment: I hadn't explored Dictionary's before searching for an answer to this question and I REALLY don't want to have to re-write how all my sub-systems (reliant on the inventory being array) work...

Comment: I don't really understand your "search" feature. Could you provide some sample input/output perhaps?

Comment: Your "search" will more then likely need a loop, not an `if`. Are you trying to search for an amount and return an ID? Or search for an ID and return an amount? Or both? Or neither?

Comment: @LaurieWalpole: Honestly, it won't take much refactoring to use a Dictionary, and the Dictionary will likely be much faster than whatever you were going to do to do lookups. Just make it a Dictionary<int, int> instead of trying to use a jagged array to do this, you can do `inv[0] = 1`

Comment: You really should take @ErikPhilips advice and use an a Dictionary. 2D arrays aren't the easiest thing to work with in .NET (jagged arrays or lists of lists are easier) and using a dictionary will make lookups much faster.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - It is not a feature currently inside of the code, it is what I am asking for help with :P But for example, when I add an item to the players inventory, as such: Items.Add(1, 100) - this adds 100 gold, I want the system to first of all CHECK the inventory array to see if it already contains an item id of "1" and if it does, to add the 100 gold to that slot in the array.

Comment: I will take a look into Dictionary, thanks for the help guys.

Comment: The problem is, how do we know `Items.Add(1, 100)` adds 100 gold? Obviously `1` is the ID for gold, but how is that coded?

Comment: @LaurieWalpole with a dictionary that would be `if(inv.ContainsKey(id)) inv[id] += amount; else inv[id] = amount;`

Comment: So, as far as I can understand your structure you have an array where the first index is just an ordinal (presumably) and then you have data contained in the first (id) and second (amount) entries of the second dimension. You'd be a lot better off using *actual objects*. Like an object with an `Id` property and an `Amount` property. Then you have a `MyObject[]` or even better a `List<MyObject>` instead of 2D arrays. But still a dictionary (of MyObject) would be better for look ups.

Comment: @Icemanind It's sounds like it's magic numbers.  An enum would be a better design.

Comment: @Icemanind - that is in my first code block on the main topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments suggest, you should use a `Dictionary` for such a task. But if you *have to* use a 2-d array, which is (i presume) pre-populated with zeros before we add any items to it, then an `if-else` statement like you propose won't do the trick. What you need to do is iterate through the array looking for a matching `id` first and each time your `id`s don't match, you have to check if the `id` that you're currently checking is equal to 0. If it is, then you have traversed all "slots" which had some items in them without finding a match, which means this item must go into another, empty slot.

```
public static void add(int id, int amount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Ship_Builder.Player.invCount; i++)
    {
        if (Ship_Builder.Player.inv[i, 0] != id)
        {
            if (Ship_Builder.Player.inv[i, 0] == 0)
            {
                Ship_Builder.Player.inv[i, 0] = id; 
                Ship_Builder.Player.inv[i, 1] = amount;
                Ship_Builder.Player.invCount++; 

                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Ship_Builder.Player.inv[i, 1] += amount;

            continue;
        }
    }
}
```

**Warning!** My answer assumes that you locate new items in the empty slot with the smallest possible index. Also, if you are removing items and setting the `id` to zero as a result, then you'll have to traverse the whole array first in search of a matching index before you can allocate a new item. Which might get very expensive time-wise if the array is large.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, it returned a out of range exception, but I am working it out now - the array has a max length of 50 so it should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on here (and there isn't enough detail to give any answer except in broad strokes), but how I would approach something like this would be to start with using *object* oriented designs rather than relying on indexed positions in arrays. I'd define something like this:

```
public class InventoryItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    // Now I can add other useful properties here too
    // ...like Name perhaps?
}
```

Now I'd make my inventory a `Dictionary<int,InventoryItem>` and adding something to my inventory might look something like this:

```
public void Add(int id, int amount) 
{
    // assuming myInventory is our inventory
    if (myInventory.ContainsKey(id)) {
        myInventory[id].Amount += amount;
    }
    else {
        myInventory[id] = new InventoryItem() 
        {
            Id = id,
            Amount = amount
        };
    }
}
```

Now it's not *necessary* that you actually use the `InventoryItem` class, you could just stick with `Dictonary<int,int>`, but you'll probably find as you work through it that you'd much rather have some objects to work with.

Then you could probably have a master dictionary of all objects and just add them to your inventory, so you end up with something like:

```
public void Add(InventoryItem item, int amount) 
{
    // assuming myInventory is our inventory
    if (myInventory.ContainsKey(item.Id)) {
        myInventory[item.Id].Amount += amount;
    }
    else {
        myInventory[item.Id] = new InventoryItem(item)   // assuming you added a 
                                                         // copy constructor, for example
        {
            Amount = amount
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the amazing answer, I may switch to using Dictionary at a later date, but for now I will stick to my current system.

Comment: The only thing I would change is the ID to an Enum.  Would make code reading/writing so much simplier to say `myInventory[Inventory.Gold]` etc..

Answer (score 0):

Depending on speed performance requirements (using arrays should be only slightly faster than this) you could just skip the hard coded values and arrays all together.  This has a few semi-advanced topics:

```
public abstract class InventoryItem
// or interface
{
  public abstract string Name { get; }
  public int Count { get; set; }
}

public class InventoryGold : InventoryItem 
{
  public string Name { get { return "Gold" } }
}

public abstract class InventoryWeapon : InventoryItem { }

public class OgreSlayingKnife : InventoryWeapon
{
  public string Name { get { return "Ogre Slaying Knife"; } }
  public int VersusOgres { get { return +9; } }
}

public UpdateCount<Item>(this ICollection<Item> instance, 
  int absoluteCount)
{
  var item = instance.OfType<Item>().FirstOrDefault();

  if (item == null && absoluteCount > 0)
  {
    item = default(Item);
    item.Count = absoluteCount;
    instance.add(item);
  }
  else
  {
    if (absoluteCount > 0)
      item.Count = absoluteCount;
    else
      instance.Remove(item);
  }
}

// Probably should be a Hashset
var inventory = new List<InventoryItem>();

inventory.UpdateCount<InventoryGold>(10);

inventory.UpdateCount<OgreSlayingKnife(1)
```